# Qt Styles - Two-Colored Border?

Tags: c++, css, qt, qt5, qt-creator

Is it possible to achieve a *two-color* border like the one in the following picture (black/gray) using Qt styles?

[image]

I've already tried to set the border style to `groove` (see my example below) but in this case the "2nd" color seems to be automatically generated based upon the first color setting. When I set the border color to black, the resulting "2nd" color becomes black, too.

```
QFrame#MainWorkspace{
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    border: 2px groove #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

So, how can I achieve a two-colored border where each color is settable individually?

Answer (score -1):

```css
body{background-color: #3a3a3a;}
.MainWorkspace{
    width:30px;
    height:24px;
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    border: 2px groove #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color:#FF0000;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:6px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(234,234,234,0.9);
    margin:5px 1px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="MainWorkspace" class="MainWorkspace">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
<div  class="MainWorkspace">
<i class="fa fa-th"></i>
</div
```